# Cleaner way instead of running the function every second

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple Coin System with JavaScript. And to make Upgrades, I made a button that gets enabled when it's over 10. To make this permanently I run this function every millisecond with this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  // My code is here
}, 1);
```

Anyway, is there a cleaner way to run this system without running the function every millisecond? It looks like this isn't clean code

Here is the code I made for the Coin-System-Thing:

```js
var numberCounter = 0;
var number = document.getElementById("number");

function plusOne() {
    numberCounter++;
  number.innerHTML = numberCounter;
}

function minusOne() {
    numberCounter--;
  number.innerHTML = numberCounter;
}


/* Disable Buttons when below 10 */

window.setInterval(function(){
if(number.innerHTML <=9){
  document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = false;
}
}, 1);
```

```html
<button onclick="plusOne();">+1</button>
<button onclick="minusOne();">-1</button>
<p id="number">0</p>

<button id="enableMe">Enabled when 10 or over</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, just do the update when you make a change.

Comment: Just change the state on click?

Comment: Also, you are caching `number`, which is a good idea, but since you are traversing the DOM a thousand times per second to look for a button, it would also be a good idea to cache `enableMe`

Comment: @Keith and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make an update function on click. No need to continuously run a function a thousand times per second.
Also start with your button disabled (since the counter starts at 0).

```js
var numberCounter = 0;
var number = document.getElementById("number");

function plusOne() {
  numberCounter++;
  number.innerHTML = numberCounter;
  updateButton();
}

function minusOne() {
  numberCounter--;
  number.innerHTML = numberCounter;
  updateButton();
}

function updateButton() {
  enableMe.disabled = (+number.innerHTML < 10)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="plusOne();">+1</button>
<button onclick="minusOne();">-1</button>
<p id="number">0</p>

<button id="enableMe" disabled>Enabled when 10 or over</button>
```

Actually, by optimizing a little, it can even be a one-liner!

```js
const change = amount => enableMe.disabled = (number.innerHTML = +number.innerHTML + amount) < 10;
```

```html
<button onclick="change(1)">+1</button>
<button onclick="change(-1)">-1</button>
<p id="number">0</p>

<button id="enableMe" disabled>Enabled when 10 or over</button>
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you so much, this is perfect :)

Comment: No worries! I even found a way to reduce my three lines of code to just one :)

Comment: Hi Jeremy, sorry to bother you but how can i add a multiply button? I'm sorry i'm a beginner in JavaScript

Comment: Well, give it a go. Try it, and if you're stuck, Stackoverflow is here to help. However we're not supposed to write your code or develop your app for you. You have to try something, show your attempt (as you did very well with your original question above). If you're stuck with the multiplication, you'll have to create a new question though. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Just create a function `enableButton` as below and call it after the click of both `+1` and `-1` button

```
function enableButton() {
  if (number.innerHTML <= 9) {
    document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = false;
  }
};
```

or

```
function enableButton() {
  document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = number.innerHTML <= 9;
};
```

**2)** You also have to handle the case for the first time before any botton press then you just call the `enableButton` function.

```js
var numberCounter = 0;
var number = document.getElementById("number");

function plusOne() {
  numberCounter++;
  number.innerHTML = numberCounter;
  enableButton()
}

function minusOne() {
  numberCounter--;
  number.innerHTML = numberCounter;
  enableButton()
}

enableButton();

function enableButton() {
  if (number.innerHTML <= 9) {
    document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("enableMe").disabled = false;
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="plusOne();">+1</button>
<button onclick="minusOne();">-1</button>
<p id="number">0</p>

<button id="enableMe">Enabled when 10 or over</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is a nice solution :)